# Typeset \chapter also in two columns when writing in twocolumn mode

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, chapters, two-column

I use

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrreprt}
```

which produces a nice layout but every chapter is set in one column mode, which leads to a new page for every chapter. **How can I tell latex to set chapters also in twocolumn mode.**

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Long one column chapter text which spans whole page}
\section{Section 1 in two column mode which breaks at some point}
\chapter{Long one column chapter text which spans whole page}
\section{Section 2 in two column mode which breaks at some point}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is, I think `status-bydesign`. But I imagine there might be chapter styles that split into two columns...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `multicol` package to create the two columns. Then they also work for the chapter headings. AFAIK it is OK to wrap the whole document in a `multicols` environment like shown below, but I never used it with a bigger document before.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\chapter{Long one column chapter text which spans whole page}
\section{Section 1 in two column mode which breaks at some point}
\chapter{Long one column chapter text which spans whole page}
\section{Section 2 in two column mode which breaks at some point}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

---

To avoid the page break at every chapter you still need to to set `\clearpage` (and maybe also `\cleardoublepage`) locally to `\relax` as shown below. However, I would simply use an **article class** like `scrartcl` instead. Then you will get basically the same format but with `\section` as the main level heading.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text only
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

{\let\clearpage\relax
\chapter{Long one column chapter text which spans whole page}}
\section{Section 1 in two column mode which breaks at some point}
\lipsum

{\let\clearpage\relax
\chapter{Long one column chapter text which spans whole page}}
\section{Section 2 in two column mode which breaks at some point}
\lipsum

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrreprt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@topnewpage[#1]{#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Long one column chapter text which spans whole page}
\section{Section 1 in two column mode which breaks at some point}
\chapter{Long one column chapter text which spans whole page}
\section{Section 2 in two column mode which breaks at some point}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looked at first exactly like what I wanted, but after the second chapter all following chapters have formatting issues: Wrong indentation and line spacing issues.

Comment: This works for me. Thanks