# memoir document class (two-column mode): how to change between default and article-mode chapter settings?

Tags: chapters, memoir, two-column

I am typesetting a document with the memoir document class with 'twocolumn' passed in the setting and I would like to be able to switch between the 'article' setting for chapters (i.e., that the chapter is embedded in the column)
[image: w/ article included in options for memoir]
and the default setting for chapters (i.e., that the chapter isn't embedded in the column)
[image: w/o article included in options for memoir]
throughout the course of the document.

Here is the code for these two images

```
\documentclass[
 article,
  10pt,
  oneside,
  openany,
  twocolumn
]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

the article parameter is commented out for the second image. I am aware of using the 'multicol' package to possibly achieve this [similar to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24821/typeset-chapter-also-in-two-columns-when-writing-in-twocolumn-mode) but I wanted to know if there was a way to do this natively in memoir.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. What is your reasoning for using the `article` option in the first place? It affects how `\chapter` is displayed (like section), plus sets up a few other things. What exactly are you missing from just not using the `article` option?

Comment: @daleif I am using the `article` option in order to get the chapter embedded in the text (rather than spanning both columns). I would like to know if there is a way to do that without using the `article` option or vice versa.

Comment: Ahh that was not at all obvious from my first reading of the question. Hmm, I'd say you could just use `\artopttrue \chapterstyle{article}` in the preamble and no `article` option. The `article` option sets `\artopt` to true and then then the rest of the `memoir` code loads. By setting it after you only get the macros who them self react to that switch being true.

Comment: @daleif thanks, that seems to achieve what I'm after :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `article` option sets `\ifartopt` to true (`\ifartopttrue`) and the `memoir` code then adapts it self to this. Additionally macros like `\chapter` react to the boolean value of this option. So if all we want is for `\chapter` to behave like under the `article` option, but without the rest of the settings, we can **not use** the `article` option and add

```
\ifartopttrue
\chapterstyle{article}
```

to the preamble.